# How many words does the algorithm search through in Google Ngram?

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

When I run a query for "hers" in Google Ngram Viewer, I get back the word's frequency of occurrence as a percentage. We know the outcome percentage; what's the denominator on the other side? Is it 100 million words? More?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the total number of words is 468,491,999,592. (Approaching half a trillion)

You can obtain that figure by [downloading the latest dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html).
In that dataset, [the `total_counts` file<sup>(txt)</sup>](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-totalcounts-20120701.txt) lists the number of unigrams, pages, and books for each year.
Summing up the unigram counts yields the 468,491,999,592 figure.

**Important notes:**

1. Currently (Nov 2015), the latest Ngram data is the *Version 20120701* set.  It was ***compiled*** in 2012, but ***covers*** books **from 1505 to 2008.**
2. A **unigram is mostly the same as a word**. Details of Google's parsing may yield differences in (hopefully) rare cases.
3. **Only words within sentences are counted.** Reference: [*Syntactic Annotations for the Google Books Ngram Corpus*<sup>(PDF)</sup>](https://aclanthology.org/P12-3029.pdf), section 3.2.
4. The percent displayed on **the graph is *normalized*** per year. This means that there is no one "denominator" if you are trying to figure the real counts of a given word. (But you can get that data from the downloaded datasets.) See below.

---

### How the graph is calculated:

Consider the word "circumvallate" (all lower case).  From the data download, we look up the 1978 and 1979 figures and get:

| Word | Count in 1978 books | Count in 1979 books |
| --- | --- | --- |
| circumvallate | 335 | 261 |
| *All words* | 4,365,839,878 | 4,528,331,460 |

Which calculates out as:

- 0.0000076732% in 1978
- 0.0000057637% in 1979

If we then look at [the corresponding graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circumvallate&year_start=1978&year_end=1980&corpus=15&smoothing=0), and hover over the respective points, we get:

[image: Sample graph]

Which agrees with what we calculate.